# Minimal distance to an obstacle using pointcluds

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like know the minimal distance from the robot platform to some obstacle. I have laser, Kinect and IMU as well but would like to use the Kinect. I think PCL library is good start as I dont need any transform of depth images. But Im absolute beginners in this and need some help to start. So I need to install PCL library, yes?? Thank have to find the point in the point clouds with the maximal or minimal values that correspond to the furthest and closest point the object , yes?? Than how to calculate the distance between that point and the robot platform?? Any help??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66177/minimal-distance-to-an-obstacle-using-pointcluds/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use openni_launch package for obtaining the kinect pointcloud. Then write a node that subscribes to the topic with a callback pcl::PointCloud  < pcl::PointXYZ>. ROS will do the conversion for you. Then just access the Z values to get your minimal distance. One of the ways to implement this is shown here http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1